# Moving in different directions around a point (planet)

Tags: c++, matrix, rotation, directx

I'm working on a game that involves moving around a planet and have currently got the player moving in one direction using forward and back using:

```
if( forward)
  yAngle = yAngle + 0.005f;
if( backward)
  yAngle = yAngle - 0.005f;
if(left)
  zAngle = zAngle - 0.005f;
if(right)
  zAngle = zAngle + 0.005f;
```

Then these angles are put into the matrix.

The character rotates perfectly using the Z Rotation and moves forward and backwards orbiting the planet using the Y rotation but will only move in that direction.

How would I calculate the X and Y rotations so the character will move around the planet in the right direction?

Comment: It's not clear what the definitions of your angles are, but you need only two angles to describe the orientation of a vector (e.g. from the coordinate origin to the player's ship) relative to the axes of a 3D coordinate system.  You can describe it in terms of rotations around any two Cartesian axes, too, but you cannot independently do rotations around all three.  You could also consider defining your rotations with respect to [spherical polar coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rotation matrix for a rotation around the x-axis of a 3D Cartesian coordinate system is

```
     1            0            0
     0        cos(xAngle)  sin(xAngle)
     0       -sin(xAngle)  cos(xAngle)
```

The matrix for a rotation around the y-axis is

```
 cos(yAngle)      0       -sin(yAngle)
     0            1            0
 sin(yAngle)      0        cos(yAngle)
```

The matrix for a rotation around the z-axis is

```
 cos(zAngle)  sin(zAngle)      0
-sin(zAngle)  cos(zAngle)      0
     0            0            1
```

You can reverse the sense of rotation of any of those matrices by reversing the signs of its sine terms.

There is no unique definition or matrix for a combined rotation about two axes, however, because the result depends on the order in which the rotations are performed.  Of particular relevance to your case, it is still different if the rotations are performed in a series of small, alternating steps.

Therefore, rather than tracking overall rotation angles, I suggest keeping a transformation matrix describing the current orientation (so that, for example, the current direction to the ship is `M` * (1, 0, 0)).  Update that on each tick, or otherwise as needed, by multiplying it by incremental rotation matrices of the above forms describing the movement since the last update.  This should give you smooth movement consistent with intuitive controls.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Implemented it using this and can move around it fine now

Answer (score 1):

I suggest trying something like this:

```
if (forward) {
  xAngle += 0.005f * (cos(zAngle));
  yAngle += 0.005f * (sin(zAngle));
}
if (backward) {
  xAngle -= 0.005f * (cos(zAngle));
  yAngle -= 0.005f * (sin(zAngle));
}
```

I'm going on a hunch here, but try it out!

Comment: Thanks, it was something similar